# Pegar imagens da pasta drawable pelo nome

Tags: java, android, listview, drawable

Gostaria de saber como pegar o id de uma imagem da pasta drawable e usar em um ImageView. Estou tentado fazer isso dentro de uma ListView

```
String nomeImgFilme = filme.getImagem();
int imgID = convertView.getResources().getIdentifier(nomeImgFilme, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```

Estou tentando executar esse código, mas ele dá erro :

> "Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060054".

E se eu colocar a imagem diretamente com "R.drawable.circulo_fogo", também diz que não foi encontrado.

Então, como eu faço pra pegar a id de uma imagem pelo nome dentro de uma ListView?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar este código para capturar o id a partir do nome do drawable

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("minha_imagem_1", "drawable", 
   context.getPackageName());
imageview.setImageResource(resourceId);
```

Espero que ajude!